# Powershell Selenium List all id elements

Tags: powershell, selenium

In short, I'm trying to archive messages in a Discord channel. Each id has a chat-message-uniqueID and I want to be able to pull them in a variable for processing. See attached image for example.

[image: Chat Message]

$driver.FindElementByXPath("//*[contains(@id, 'chat-messages-')]")
Looks to return one result...

$driver.FindElementsByXPath("//*[contains(@id, 'chat-messages-')]") Elements returns the last 100. Solved.

Comment: What have you searched for? What have you tried? Show your code and errors, expected results. SO, has rules to follow. [Provide MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) --- [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) --- [Don't ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) --- [Proper Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) --- [Why not upload images of code/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 0):

$driver.FindElementsByXPath("//*[contains(@id, 'chat-messages-')]") Elements returns the last 100. Solved.